# FB.login e bloqueio de pop-ups

Tags: javascript, facebook, popup, facebook-javascript-sdk

Estou com um problema de usabilidade na hora de requisitar de permissões extras no Facebook.

Conforme documentação do Facebook a função [`FB.login`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) só deve ser chamada depois de um click pois a maioria dos navegadores bloqueia pop-ups abertas por qualquer outro meio.

O problema ocorre quando estou utilizando a função `FB.login` no meio da minha aplicação com o intuito de requisitar permissões extras para postar uma imagem (conforme melhores práticas do Facebook deixo para requisitar essa permissão no último momento).

Antes de requisitar a permissão eu verifico se o usuário já não a concedeu anteriormente. O que me levou à seguinte construção:

### Função para checagem de permissões:

```
function checkPermissions(perms, callback, failCallback) {
    FB.api('/me/permissions', function (response) {
        var fbPerms = response.data[0];
        var haveAllPermissions = true;

        if (typeof perms === 'string') {
            perms = [ perms ];
        }

        for (var i in perms) {
            if (fbPerms[perms[i]] == null) {
                haveAllPermissions = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (haveAllPermissions) {
            callback();
        } else {
            failCallback();
        }
    });
}
```

## A versão "quebrada"

Usa a seguinte construção (ativada por um clique em um botão):

```
  // Verifica permissões
  checkPermissions("publish_actions",
      // Em caso de sucesso cria o request
      generateRequest,
      // Em caso de fracasso
      function () {
          // requisita a permissão
          FB.login(function () {
              // Verifica a permissão novamente
              checkPermissions("publish_actions",
                  // Em caso de sucesso cria o request
                  generateRequest,
                  // Em caso de fracasso notifica o usuário
                  function () {
                      alert("Permissão negada");
                        // Reativa o botão para postar colagens 
                        $("#gerarColagem").one('click', enviaColagem);
                  });
          }, {scope: "publish_actions"});
      });
```

Vocês podem ver o código em ação http://sfcb.7rtc.com (clicando no botão Postar).

## O problema

Como estou checando pela permissão `publish_actions` a pop-up não está diretamente atrelada ao click. Mesmo sendo um click que ativa o fluxo, a chamada para `FB.login` está na verdade atrelada a um `callback`. Resultado: Navegadores estão bloqueando a pop-up de login.

## A solução não desejável

Eu posso pular a primeira checagem por permissões e forçar um fluxo de `login` sempre (se o usuário já atribuiu a permissão tudo ocorre silenciosamente):

```
 FB.login(function () {
     // Verifica a permissão novamente
     checkPermissions("publish_actions",
         // Em caso de sucesso cria o request
         generateRequest,
         // Em caso de fracasso notifica o usuário
         function () {
             alert("Permissão negada");
             // Reativa o botão para postar colagens 
             $("#gerarColagem").one('click', enviaColagem);
         });
 }, {scope: "publish_actions"});
```

Nesse caso (pulando a primeira checagem de permissões) a pop-up abre normalmente uma vez que o método `FB.login` está respondendo diretamente ao click. O aspecto negativo é que ela está chamando o método de login todas as vezes, fazendo com que usuários que já garantiram a permissão anteriormente lidem com um *overhead* desnecessário e recorrente.

No cenário feliz o usuário concederá a permissão logo na primeira vez que clicar em "Postar". A versão "quebrada" garante que esses usuários não passem por um fluxo de login desnecessariamente; tudo funciona corretamente depois da primeira autorização.

---

Dessa forma, minha pergunta é: Como estruturar minhas chamadas para fazer e requisição de permissão com `FB.login` sem que o navegador bloqueie a pop-up do Facebook? Existe alguma maneira de checar as permissões antes de chamar o `FB.login` sem que o navegador bloqueie a pop-up?

---

## Cenário Perfeito

1. O usuário clica em Postar
2. A aplicação verifica que o usuário possui a permissão `publish_actions`
3. A aplicação publica a foto (sem requisitar o login com permissão extra)

**Cenário alternativo:**

1. O usuário clica em Postar
2. b) A aplicação verifica que o usuário não possui a permissão `publish_actions`
3. A aplicação requisita novo login com permissão (essa janela não é bloqueada pelo navegador)
4. O usuário autoriza a permissão
5. A aplicação publica a foto

Comment: Com tantos cenários, ficou um pouco confuso de entender o cenário desejado, exatamente como você quer, poderia editar e colocar em muita relevância o seu cenário "perfeito" com o comportamento exatamente descrito?

Comment: Paulo, atualizei em formato de caso de uso. O dilema todo da coisa é que ou implemento o passo 2 conforme descrito e o passo 3 do cenário alternativa quebra (devido ao bloqueador de pop-ups) ou pulo o passo 2 e faço login sempre (estragando o cenário perfeito). Ficou mais claro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondendo minha própria pergunta para futuras referências.

Realmente a chamada para `FB.login` tem que ser feita diretamente do click ou os navegadores bloqueiam a *pop-up* de login. Porém lendo a pergunta [*"Facebook login popup blocked in IE 9"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156271/facebook-login-popup-blocked-in-ie-9) no SOE tive a inspiração de refatorar meu código da seguinte maneira:

Na inicialização da página subscrevo ao evento `authResponseChangeCallback`:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', authResponseChangeCallback);
```

Isso faz com que o *callback* `authResponseChangeCallback` seja disparado após a inicialização da API do Facebook. Se o usuário estiver conectado ao Facebook o *callback* verifica a permissão `publish_actions`. O botão "Postar" só é exibido após essa consulta:

```
if (response.status === 'connected') {
  FB.api('/me/permissions', function (response) {
    var fbPerms = response.data[0];
    var autorizado = (fbPerms.publish_actions != null);
    var botaoPostar = $("#gerarColagem");
    botaoPostar.data("autorizado", autorizado);
    botaoPostar.show();
  });
}
```

Essa função armazena uma propriedade `autorizado` em um atributo *data* do botão.

Durante o *click* no botão "Postar", ao invés de checar diretamente pela permissão `publish_actions`, apenas recupero o valor do atributo `autorizado`. Dessa forma, havendo necessidade de login a *pop-up* é disparada no contexto do *click*, eliminando o problema das *pop-ups* boqueadas.

```
var autorizado = $(this).data("autorizado");
// Usuario tem permissao para publicar
if (autorizado) {
  generateRequest()
}
// Usuario não possui permissão para publicar
else {
  // requisita a permissão
  FB.login(function () {
    // Verifica a permissão novamente
    checkPermissions("publish_actions",
      // Em caso de sucesso cria o request
      generateRequest,
      // Em caso de fracasso notifica o usuário
      function () {
        alert("Permissão negada");
        // Reativa o botão para postar colagens 
        $("#gerarColagem").one('click', enviaColagem);
  });
}
```

Essa solução resolve os conflitos mencionados na pergunta.

Alguns casos artificiais podem gerar problemas, por exemplo, o usuário pode:

1. Conceder a permissão
2. Acessar a página, o que armazena `autorizado = true` no botão "Postar"
3. Entrar no Facebook em outra aba
4. Excluir a permissão `publish_actions` do aplicativo
5. Voltar a aba no aplicativo e clicar em "Postar"

Mas esse é um caso tão artificial que inicialmente não vejo nenhum problema em deixar a aplicação falhar.